# Jquery Datatables in rails 7 application requires hard refresh after first navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

This is my application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="language" content="en"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="PNA, PNA Result, Punjab Nursing Admission System"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Punjab Nursing Admission System">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", async: true%>
        <%= javascript_include_tag("turbo", type: "module") %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer-sync var2">
            <%= render partial: 'partials/header' %>
            <%= render partial: 'partials/messages' %>
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
        <%= render partial: 'partials/footer' %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is I have different pages where on every page, jquery datatable is being used. Now when I land on the page after login and layout is set as application.html.erb, It shows me correct datatable styling and js but when I navigate to some other page, it stops showing me datatable css and js. I have also seen trying to disable turbolinks requires full page reload and does the work perfectly.
below is my content of application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require maskedinput
//= require vendor/bootstrap.min
//= require jquery.easing.min
//= require modernizr
//= require plugins
//= require jquery.selectbox-0.2
//= require icheck.min
//= require plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min
//= require plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require custom/application_layout_datatable_date_picker
//= require custom/application_layout_masking
```

Below is my content of application.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require jquery.selectbox
 *= require styles
 *= require responsive
 *= require plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker.min
 *= require skins/all
 */
```